# Verifying a DoS / DDoS attack on a network dump (PCAP file)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from scapy.all import *
import dpkt

f1 = open("semAtaque.pcap")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f1)
f1.close()

f2 = open("Ataques.pcap")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f2)
f2.close()
```

I have two network traffic from lab experiment: one free of attacks (semAtaque.pcap) and another with DDoS attacks (Attacks.pcap).

In order to verify if the experiment was valid, I need to first check if the server denied the service, when it happened and how the server buffer was during the entire attack (Attacks.pcap).

The IP of the server that suffered the attack: 192.168.1.5

How to check the state of the server buffer before and after the attack?

How to check if the server denied the service and when did it occur?

```
before attack -> Server buffer : the number of connections that server can handle!

after attack ->Server buffer: the number of connections that was request to the  server. If its > than before attack, it will be DDoS!
```

I need to know how many connection was request to the server before it crashes!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "server buffer," but it sounds like something you'd need to instrument your server to get, and not something that would show up in a .pacp file.

Comment: @charlesreid1:  before attack -> Server buffer : the number of connections that server can handle!
    
    after attack ->Server buffer: the number of connections that was request to the  server. If its > than before attack, it will be DDoS!

I need to know how many connection was request to the server before it crashes!!

Comment: @charlesreid1, could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple lambda function in Python to extract the source and destination IP addresses from packets, so I combined that with a queue to compute a moving average, and designed this script around it. It's a hack, but it'll do what you need.

To get a sense of how the server's service (or lack thereof) varies with time, you can loop through all of the packets, and look for packets with the server's IP as the source or destination. If a packet is being sent to the server, we'll call that +1, and if a packet is being sent from the server, we'll call that -1. Now we can start to quantify whether traffic is incoming or outgoing.

Putting this all together, we use a Python double-ended queue (deque) with a fixed length (that's your window size) to move through the packets, and when we find a packet going to or from the server, we store a +1 or a -1 in the deque. And now, if we take the average of all the numbers in the deque, we'll get a measure of the ratio of outbound to inbound traffic for that server. An average near -1 means the moving window is mostly seeing outbound traffic from the server; an average of 0 means we have an equal number of outbound and inbound packets; and an average closer to +1 means we have heavy inbound traffic. This will print the average of all the values in the queue.

This uses a moving window of 30 packets; that will definitely need to be adjusted to your traffic level. This sifts through each packet and populates the queue as it finds packets meeting the criteria. Once the queue is full, it will pop old values and push new values, advancing the 30-packet or N-packet moving window forward, and printing the average of all the dequeue values in the window each time it advances the window.

```
from scapy.all import *
from collections import deque

def print_attack_measure(pcap_file):
    plist = rdpcap(pcap_file)
    server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
    n = 300
    d = deque(maxlen=n)

    # If you want source/destination IP addresses
    getsrcdst = lambda x:(x.src,x.dst)
    # If you want MAC addresses
    getmacs   = lambda x:(x.addr1, x.addr2, x.addr3)

    def filterpackets(ip):
        for p in plist:
            try:
                c = getsrcdst(p)
                if(ip in c[0]):
                    # server IP is source IP of packet
                    yield -1
                if(ip in c[1]):
                    # server IP is destination IP of packet
                    yield 1
            except AttributeError:
                pass


    print("This prints a measure of packets received to packets sent, using a moving average of %d packets."%(n))
    print("0 indicates a perfect balance of sent-received.")
    print("+1 indicates all packets are sent to the server.")
    print("-1 indicates all packets are sent by the server.")
    print("A larger positive number indicates an unresponsive server.")

    count = 0
    for pack in filterpackets(server_ip):
        d.append(pack)
        count += 1
        if(count>n):
            print("%0.4f"%(sum(d)/(1.0*n)))
```

Then you can call the function on your two pcap files, and examine/compare the output:

```
print_attack_measure("semAtaque.pcap")
print_attack_measure("Ataques.pcap")
```

You could also change the print function above to print to a file, and visualize the output in Matplotlib or a spreadsheet program.

**Note:** this script uses a rate of packet arrival, not a time-based rate, to compute changes in server availability, but this is a good first-pass solution. You could use this as a basis to design something time-based by (for example) extracting the timestamp from each packet, binning up packets by time interval (using a dictionary), and using the +1/-1 system again.

**EDIT:** IThere is a way to read large pcap files one packet at a time instead of loading them into memory. The example at the end of the [Scapy Readme](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/#reading-huge-pcap-file):

```
with PcapReader('filename.pcap') as pcap_reader:
    for pkt in pcap_reader:
        #do something with the packet
```

You would replace

```
    plist = rdpcap(pcap_file)
```

with this:

```
    with PcapReader(pcap_file) as plist:
```

Related [Scapy issue on Github](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/issues/7).

Comment: Is there a way to not put the complete PCAP file into the memory RAM?? PCAP files are about 2 GB and I can not run the script!

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: The pastebin code doesn't match the code above. The four print functions were indented one level too many, so they're in the def filterpackets() function when they should happen after the function definition (they're part of the print_attack_measure() function, not the filterpackets() function). The filterpackets() function definition should end with the "except AttributeError: pass". Try de-indenting lines 30 through 41 of your pastebin code.

Comment: @@charlesreid1:It is the error: http://imgur.com/a/KC87V     NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: It is still not copied and pasted correctly - the statement using n needs to be inside the scope of the print_attack_measure function. Match the indentation in the original code I posted, or use this Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6016559efa40858d74e8dc61f3f00bb

Comment: Updated with links/info about how to use Scapy to read packets directly from the file instead of loading the entire pcap into memory.